# have somebody do something vs. have somebody doing something

Tags: meaning, grammar, differences, meaning-in-context

*History, as recounted by the victors, had the capitalists winning.*

I think that the above sentence means that history caused the capitalists to win. Can I say

*History, as recounted by the victors, had the capitalists win*?

What is the difference between the structure *have somebody doing something* and *have somebody do something*?

Comment: Your interpretation of the original sentence is incorrect. It means that the victors reported that the capitalists won, no cause is implied.

Comment: The gerund _winning_ is used to turn _win_ from a verb to a noun, so that it can be something that can be _had_. In this case, _had_ means _contained_ or _included_.

Comment: Somebody might have written a book that *had the communists **win***. It's largely a stylistic choice which verb form to use, though the *exact* context will affect that choice. The ***-ing*** form has a greater sense of "immediacy" and relevance to the time of utterance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To *have somebody do something* most commonly means to cause somebody to do something (eg, ask, force, pay). But in this sentence the verb *had* means something like believed, perceived, recorded, claimed, or stated.

*The clerk said the robber was tall and blond, but another witness had the robber as being of average height with red hair.*

The history that the victors created claimed that the capitalists were the winners. More simply: The victors claimed that the capitalists were the winners. The rhetorical style suggests that the writer *may* be expressing disagreement with or doubt about that claim.

There are many reasons for chosing an -ing form over another type of word, sometimes more than one reason in a particular instance. Here, the primary purpose was to avoid the phrase *to have somebody win*, which suggests that *have* means *cause*. We would need more context to figure out if the -ing form is also related to a time aspect. I would guess not, as it probably functions here as a verbal noun instead of a present participle.

Answer (score 11):

Verb - clean

I have somebody cleaning the floor. (Someone is cleaning it right now.)

I will have somebody clean the floor. (Someone will clean it in the undetermined near future.)

I am having someone clean the floor. (Someone will clean the floor in the determined near future.)

I have somebody clean the floor. (Someone cleans the floor regularly for me.)

I have somebody doing the cleaning. (Someone is cleaning, but more than just a relatively quick job.)

I have somebody doing the cleaning of the floor. (Correct in formart, a bit quirky in style, and essentially means the same as the first example.)

Note: The last example would probably be used more with the word 'already' to emphasize that there is a whole complete task organized.

I already have somebody doing the cleaning of the floor.

Comment: *I have somebody clean the floor* is not incorrect; it can be something that happens on a regular basis.

Comment: Not responsive to the OP's issue. The problem stems principally from assuming the incorrect definition of "have".

Comment: @tunny, thanks for catching that. i'll edit that. (at)jim, i see the question "What is the difference between structure.... " I just added extra alternatives.

Comment: @tunny - i am starting to second guess that. it doesn't sound natural to me. What would be more natural is "I have somebody to clean the floor."

Comment: What about "I had somebody clean the floor"? For something done in the past.