# To have somebody do something

Tags: sentence, sentence-patterns

Hi could anyone tell me if my following sentences are right? (English U.S about "have somebody do something")

1. I made Mary take out the trash
2. I usually have her take out the trash
3. I'm having her take out the trash
4. Did you have him take out the trash?
5. Have you had her take out the trash
6. Did you make her take out the trash?

Thanks for everything

Comment: The noun "trash" is rarely plural in the US.

Comment: The sentences are grammatical (but 3,4,5 not very idiomatic). You would only speak in this way if the person is a servant or other employee.

Comment: Even in US ????

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/208233/have-somebody-do-something-vs-have-somebody-doing-something